# Write text to non-contigous regions

Tags: tables

Not really sure how to describe this best so here is a picture:

[image]

In essence, I want rows 1 and 2 to pretend to be one row (with line breaks acting normally), and the same for rows 3 and 4.

Additionally, all "cells" should be the same horizontal and vertical size, with the text lining up if row 1 was overlaid with row 2 (and same for 3 and 4 of course).

Here is the horrible horrible code used to generate the image:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|p{\dimexpr.1\textwidth}|p{\dimexpr.1\textwidth}|p{\dimexpr.1\textwidth}|p{\dimexpr.1\textwidth}|p{\dimexpr.1\textwidth}|p{\dimexpr.1\textwidth}}
\hline
\parbox{2cm}{This \\ on and} && is some && text & \\
\hline
&\parbox{2cm}{that \\on} && I want && to flow \\
\hline
This && should && be a & \\
\hline
& whole && separate && sentance \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

**NOTE:** While I am currently using tabular, I would be happy to be rid of it and do this in Tikz, or really anything else.

Comment: Is this the only use-case? Or does your document contain other stuff? The reason I'm asking is that in a general setting, you can use [`flowfram`](http://ctan.org/pkg/flowfram) to structure this layout, and it's fairly easy to do so without having anything else in your document...

Comment: @Werner this is to make a chinese finger trap with writing on it, so yes, this is the only text in the document?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle My primary concern is how to many it work. I fundamentally don't think that `tabularx` is suited to the problem (though I don't really know) but its how I made the example of what I was looking for

Comment: Oh hang on: you want the text to flow naturally across with certain words positioned underneat specific words as a kind of annotation? Then a table probably isn't what you want.

Comment: I see (sort of) what you want the output to look like.  But one important question is how would you like your input to the lines to flow?  For example, "this on and & is some & text\\that on & I want& to flow" as opposed to "This is some thext that I want to flow on and on"

Comment: Is something like the top and bottom lapping commands of the `stackengine` package helpful (http://ctan.org/pkg/stackengine)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`flowfram`](http://ctan.org/pkg/flowfram) enables one to specify frames (blocks) on a page that the text should flow frame. The following MWE creates a staggered row of blocks that can be adjusted in terms of the number of rows/columns and block dimension:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{flowfram,multido}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{flowfram,multido}
\usepackage[landscape,margin=1in]{geometry}

\showframebboxtrue% Show blocks
\newlength{\blockwidth}\setlength{\blockwidth}{7\baselineskip}% Block dimensions
\newlength{\blockL}\newlength{\blockB}
\newflowframe{\blockwidth}{\blockwidth}{0pt}{\dimexpr\textheight-\blockwidth}% First block
\multido{\iRow=0+1,\iRowIndex=0+1}{4}{% NUMBER OF ROWS
  % Calculate Base of block
  \setlength{\blockB}{\dimexpr\textheight-\number\numexpr\iRow+1\relax\blockwidth}%
  \multido{\iCol=0+2}{3}{% NUMBER OF COLUMNS
    % Calculate Left edge of block
    \setlength{\blockL}{\dimexpr\iCol\blockwidth}%
    \ifodd\iRowIndex\addtolength{\blockL}{\blockwidth}\fi% Step blocks every other row
    \ifnum\numexpr\iRow+\iCol=0\relax% First block already created
    \else\newflowframe{\blockwidth}{\blockwidth}{\blockL}{\blockB}\fi% Subsequent blocks
  }%
}%

\begin{document}

\raggedright
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis interdum auctor turpis, 
quis condimentum enim sagittis a. Proin congue felis in laoreet dapibus. Suspendisse \framebreak
eu magna et sapien ultricies rhoncus quis a velit. Sed sed nulla tellus. Curabitur 
euismod sem nibh, ut gravida augue vulputate sed. Phasellus quis ante lectus. Proin 
massa ligula, fringilla eu lacinia in, accumsan pharetra sapien. Pellentesque habitant 
morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Praesent 
dignissim odio sapien, sed malesuada leo dictum eget. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec 
scelerisque dictum neque sit amet sagittis.

\end{document}
```

Prematurely stepping from one frame to the next is possible via `\framebreak`.

`\newflowframe{<width>}{<height>}{<x>}{<y>}` creates a "flow frame" with dimensions `<width>`x`<height>` that has its lower-left corner at (`<x>`,`<y>`).

Comment: Is there a way to get it to flow first to the next cell instead of filling the rest of the line first?

Comment: @soandos: The flow follows the order in which they are created. It seemed (from your picture) that you wanted things to flow left-to-right, top-to-bottom with a stagger/step in each row. If you wish, one can define each of the `\newflowframe`s manually to be scattered across the page in whichever order you want, and the text will flow accordingly. I don't fully understand your last comment here, but perhaps my ramblings have answered your question?

Comment: So the flow is good, but instead of flowing when the box is full (or on `\framebreak`), is it possible to have it flow at the end of the line and loop back?

Comment: @soandos: Automatically? Perhaps creating a command `\nextrow` that issues a number of `\framebreak`s until you're at the start again?

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean something like this

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength\textwidth{.5\textwidth}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}



\noindent\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{%
\setlength\baselineskip{2\baselineskip}%
This some  text that I want to flow.
This should  be a  whole  separate  sentence 
This some more  text that I want to flow.
This should  be a  whole  newseparate  sentence}%
\hspace{-\linewidth}%
\raisebox{-\baselineskip}{\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{%
\setlength\baselineskip{2\baselineskip}%
\itshape
Different text that gets stuck in the intervening lines.
Different text that gets stuck in the intervening lines.
Different text that gets stuck in the intervening lines.}}

\end{document}
```

**first guess**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength\textwidth{.5\textwidth}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}

\renewcommand\baselinestretch{2}

\newcommand\zz[2]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}#1\\\itshape#2\\\end{tabular}}

\zz{This}{on and}  is some  text \zz{that}{on} I want to flow 
This should  be a  whole  separate  sentence 


\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it so that it *flows* without me having to figure out what should go over what? Also, if it helps, there can only be text in one of the two rows in one vertical at a time.

Comment: @soandos oh so they are not annotating individual words (like ruby) you just want two independent sentences interleaved?

Comment: Yes. Apologies if I did not make that clear in the example

Comment: @soandos updated with 2nd try:-)

Comment: I am so sorry, I'm really not clear. The goal is that each line would be cut out and woven together. This means that some parts of lines will be covered, and that the text has to continue cleanly after that section. So what I am looking for is something that looks almost exactly like what I have in my example, but is *cleaner* in that the spacing works, its flexible (in terms of how many "columns" I want and the widths) and to write it does not take a lot of messing around, guessing, and overall cludgyness

Comment: @soandos OK so I have no idea what you want. Given that no one else has attempted an answer I suspect I am not the only one. I suggest that you make a complete tex file with an input source how you'd like it (make it make any non-error output, it doesn't really matter) then fake an image in paint or word or write it with a pen and take a photo, and post what you want the supplied input to produce.